# Xamarin ios - How to access a cell from a static TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, ipad, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have an issue with how my tableview is rendered on an iPad device. Despite setting the background color to clear on the story board,the tableview, when testing on the iPad always has a gray background color. I have searched around this site and found plenty of solutions:

Already tried this suggestion

```
public override void viewDidLoad() {
 base.ViewDidLoad();

tableView.backgroundView = new UIView();
tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
```

}

And I even tried to override the GetCell function inside my tableview class, so I can change the contentView color by accessing the cell, like this

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor
```

But the GetCell function is never called.

**EDIT**

Here's a sample screen from one of the screens that has a static table view

[image: screen shot]

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: can you show a screenshot of the gray background color?

Comment: @iamIcarus I added a screen shot of one of the screens and how it appears on the iPad. Thanks.

Comment: since its populating cells the **GetCell** is called. Also it looks like the cells/tableview background is white not gray?

Comment: These cells have been added via the  storyboard. It's a static table. And I am not overriding the GetCell function anywhere because I manually added the cells and text field via the storyboard. I would like to now override the GetCell function and programmatically set the background color to clear, since the storyboard changes don't reflect here. And, yes, I guess it's white. I tried to override the GetCell in my UITableViewController class, but it never gets called. Do you have any pointers on how I can do this with a static table view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days trying to solve this white background issue, I found the simplest solution that worked for me:

To solve it, simply add this line in your AppDelegate.cs file,in your `FinishedLaunching` function. This defines the appearance of all the table cells in your app (if you actually want all your tableview cells to have a clear background.)

```
    UITableViewCell.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
```

This is now rendered correctly on the iPhone as well as the iPad.

Comment: The problem with that solution is all TableViewCells backgrounds will be clear in the entire app and you may not want that. It seems like you are having more trouble properly implementing a TableView

Comment: @Nick, I don't have trouble implementing a table. I have dynamic tableviews and static ones in my app. For the static table views, I don't really need a UITableViewSource because all the cells are designed on the storyboard. That's what I meant by, I didn't see the need for defining a table source, since I can't return a specific number of rows in the RowsInSection (Rows have already been designed on the storyboard). All along, I was looking for a way to access these static tableview cells so I could change the background color.I ended up finding a simpler solution, which is now I posted above

Comment: you can return a specific number of rows by overriding RowsInSection and returning the number of cells. The cells you defined in your storyboard you would then just give an identifier and reuse them like in my example

Comment: I had already tried that Nick. My cells have an identifier, and I tried to define the CustomTableSource also. But I ended up getting an exception in the GetCell function. It couldn't return a cell from the data source. Something like that, which I found strange, because it works just fine for the dynamic tableviews.

Comment: My guess is something must have been wrong in the in your code or the storyboard for it to not have worked but without an actual error its hard to tell. I just typically create a custom cell and a table source that way whether the table is static or not I can use that same cell class on multiple screen.

Comment: Okay. Could you elaborate on how I would implement the RowsInSection without overriding the cells I've already designed on the storyboard. For instance, the table in question has 4 sections, each with a cell.So I could override the NumberOfSections function and return 4. But what do I return for the RowsInSection override? I have a row in each section.

Comment: You would then just then have a switch on the section in RowsInSection and return the number of rows for each section. Also you might want to consider if all the data and everything you're trying to show fits on the screen without scrolling it might not need to even be a TableView

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I'll try re-work the table source implementation and see how that goes for me. Although the solution I found works for me, since I want all my cells to have a clear background.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background color by overriding GetCell you want to give your custom cells an identifier in the storyboard and override GetCell in your TableViews TableSource like below. Also you might want to check that your tableView source is being set to your CustomTableSource in ViewDidLoad:

```
tableView.Source = new CustomTableSource(this);
```

Unless you are using an `IUITableViewDataSource` then check that your Weak delegate and source being set:

```
tableView.WeakDelegate = this;
tableView.WeakDataSource = this;
```

Overriding GetCell:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
     var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("CellIdentifier") as CustomCell;
     if (cell == null)
            cell = new CustomCell();
     cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear
     return cell;
}
```

You'll have to override RowsInSection as well:

```
public nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableView, nint section)
{
      return 7;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nick . Thank you for your response. I was hoping I wouldn't need to implement a UITableViewSource for a static table but I tried it anyway. The challenge is, I'm forced to implement the RowsInSection function, which doesn't really make sense here since it's a static table. The other challenge is I get another exception in the GetCell function, saying it failed to obtain the cell from the data source.

Comment: Yeah if you're implementing a Custom TableSource you'll have to override RowsInSection as well which is fine just have it return a number for the number of rows you have